# Security\Backup related to FileStream datatype

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using FileStream datatype in SQLServer 2008 to store attachments. My apprehension is on whether these files be included in the SQLServer backup and what will be the default permissions set assigned to these files on a NTFS file system?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FILESTREAM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) data is included in SQL Server backups (how could it not be so, given it's trying to give you something transactionally consistent):

> the FILESTREAM data is backed up with the structured data in the database. If you do not want to back up FILESTREAM data with relational data, you can use a partial backup to exclude FILESTREAM filegroups

I'm not sure on your second question. I had a feeling that SQL Server set's its service account as the only one with permissions on the FILESTREAM directory, hence the [following restriction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645585.aspx):

> For a FILESTREAM filegroup, FILENAME refers to a path. The path up to the last folder must exist, and the last folder must not exist

So that it can create the directory and set its security itself.